# Transparent PictureBoxes

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, picturebox

I really, really want your help. My project is next.

I have a `pictureBox1`, which is parent for all other `pictureBoxes` that I create with array. These `pictureBoxes` are smaller that I can move them on the `pictureBox1`.

For every newly created `pictureBox` I set next properties:

```
PB[i]->Parent = pictureBox1
PB[i]->BackColor = Color::Transparent
```

At the same time I set to them PNG file, whose `backcolor` is also transparent.

With a single `pictureBox` on `pictureBox1` it is OK. But when two or more `pictureBoxes` are located together they just block each other's content. I tried to bring to the front, but it ain't work. Which `pictureBox` is on top it blocks `pictureBox` below it.

How can I set or make a mutual transparency for `pictureBoxes`, while their parent is one, `pictureBox1`?

Comment: You can't.  PictureBox is one of the most wasteful controls there are, along with Label, burning up an entire window to replace a single line of code.  Point-and-click convenience, that's all.  Use Graphics::DrawImage(), it solves your problem since it layers paint.

Comment: If u are allowed then try it with WPF it may solve your problem.

Comment: Hans Passant thanks. It is a good idea. That's what i wanted.